# 構文エラー(SyntaxError: invalid syntax)の解決策を教えてください

Tags: python

以下に実際のコードを貼ります。問題はimportが終わった後の、dfのエリアで起きています。

```
#必要ライブラリのインポート
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
#import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import re
import math
import glob
#import sqldf
import scipy.stats
import os



df = pd.read_csv('inuiken.csv')
df = pd.read_csv('inuiken.csv' , encoding=)
df
```

エラー内容

```
  File "<ipython-input-7-114a3ab1e1ea>", line 2
    df = pd.read_csv('inuiken.csv' , encoding=)
                                              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: こんなにマイナスされるような質問ではないと思いますが。

Answer (score 3):

`encoding=`を`encoding="utf-8"`や`encoding="shift-jis"`のように書き換えてください。

キーワード引数を指定する場合は`=`の右辺に値を入れないと構文エラーになります。
省略することはできません。